# What causes the Sun to appear to be in front of a building in this picture?

Tags: optics, visible-light, everyday-life, sun, camera

I took this photograph a few days ago, during sunrise, using my smartphone camera and digital zoom:

[image]

It seems that the sun is in front of the building. How is this explained?

Comment: I think the diaphragm of your camera was much wide that the glow around the sun has become white and you think its the sun itself.

Comment: If you tweak the levels and knock the contrast way up, you can see that @AHB is right; the sun itself is right next to the building (the edges are just touching), and there is a distinctive glow around it (produced by the camera) which is overlapping the building.

Comment: I guess that building is much farther away than it looks.

Comment: This is also answered on [photography.se]

Comment: @JDługosz: I'll take your word for it, but it would've been a lot more useful if you'd linked to the actual Q&A answering it there.

Comment: I looked and could not find it there...

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You are seeing the effect of a combination of blurring - caused by an imperfect optical system - and saturation.

Blurring: ideally, a lens should map a point source into a point source. In reality, it is mapped into something slightly wider than that. If the image is well-focused, the lens is free of imperfections, and diffraction due to the finite size of the lens (aperture) is minimal, then that approximation is close to true. In your case, it's clear by looking at the image of the building that there is significant blurring: probably this is due to the image being slightly out of focus; perhaps atmospheric blur (scatter - light fog?) is contributing.  There is also something called *blooming* where excess exposure on one pixel causes some signal to appear on neighboring pixels. All these things contribute to a blurring of bright objects in your picture (like the sun).

Saturation: the sun is much, much brighter than the building. The exposure setting of your camera is such that an intensity that is a small fraction of the intensity of the sun causes a "fully on" pixel in the image.

In the following image I try to illustrate how a point source that is imaged through an out-of-focus lens becomes slightly blurred:

[image]

I believe that in your image, the saturation is sufficient that the edge of the sun really corresponds to part of the blurred image of the sun, as illustrated in this next image which shows the convolution of a top hat function ("the sun") with a Gaussian of different widths ("good" and "out of focus" lens).

[image]

The "saturation" line shows a possible intensity at which pixels would appear white: as you can see, for the values I chose the sun would appear larger than it really is - and therefore it would appear to "cut through" the edge of the building. Which gives the illusion that it must be in front.

Here is a 2D demonstration of what is going on - I hope the picture and legends are self-explanatory:

[image]

I had to use log scale a couple of times because the sun is so much brighter than the "building" and background in this image.

Comment: This is just a great answer!

Comment: Good answer, but would not diffraction also account for this illusion?  Just like the edges of a shadow from an distant object object would be blurred.  Or are you accounting for that in your description of blurred?

Comment: @mharr Thanks. I didn't list all possible effects of "imperfect optics" - diffraction is part of it (and of course the degree to which an object is out of focus depends on the size of the aperture - a small aperture gives good focus and a lot of diffraction, while a large aperture does the opposite). In this case I think focus, haze and blooming are the key factors. But without access to the original settings and equipment it would be hard to be definitive.

Comment: Even if the sun is blurred, shouldn't it make a difference that the building is in focus (or not *so* badly out of focus to account for the full diameter shown)? If I hold my finger in front of a light bulb, with my eye focused on my finger, the blurred image of the lightbulb doesn't seem to extend past the line of my finger.

Comment: @Random832 - "bloom" is an effect where a small fraction of light "travels laterally" across the sensor. Sometimes it's the excess charge that leaks, sometimes, it's the light itself. The point is - the combination of _any_ blurring with the thresholding of the saturated sensor gives rise to a larger-than-true image of the sun. Remember also that a blur "times 10000, then thresholded" will be a lot wider than the blur on the side of the building. The Sun subtends a solid angle of less than $10^{-4}$ srad, so it will be roughly 10000 times brighter than objects it illuminates.

Comment: Sure, but what I don't understand is why this larger-than-true image of the sun isn't still occluded by the building.

Comment: That is because the blurring happens in the camera - not at the building. At the point you don't know how far the photons traveled (assuming they were both coming "from far" so they are equally (un)focused)

Comment: @Floris would the same effects - blurring and saturation - also occur in human eyes? Would the sun seem in front of the building when looking at it with the naked eye? (I didn't check when I took the picture)

Comment: How did you manage to generate that image?

Comment: @Floris I think mharr meant diffraction of the sunlight *by the building*, not by the lens' diaphragm... I wonder how much of an effect that could have.

Comment: @TomášZato I used a few lines of Python. Unfortunately I am on the road now and the code I wrote is on my home computer...

Comment: @Lior it is possible - but don't try it! The human eye has a strong nonlinear component to detection which makes it much less prone to this kind saturation. At the same time there is all kinds of habituation - when you look away from a bright image you see it "burnt in" to your retina for a while. The sun might stay burnt in because of damage. I repeat: Don't try it.